# React Native Android - Why is absolute positioned view outside of parent component bounds cannot be interacted with?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement an autocomplete input that has a scrollview below the text input when the user starts typing which contains rows of suggestions that can be pressed. The problem only occurs on Android wherein the component below the text input which has an absolute positioning cannot be pressed or scrolled since it is outside the parent container. What is the best work around on this? I already tried changing zIndex of the parent container and also the scroll view, but it still doesn't work.

Here is a snack code url if you guys wanna test: [snack.expo.io/HkLeBYV18](http://snack.expo.io/HkLeBYV18)

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to implement, the one circled with red cannot be press or anything on Android:
[image]

Comment: can you share the code in expo-snack so that we can check

Comment: Hi, here's the expo snack code: https://snack.expo.io/HkLeBYV18 @GauravRoy

Comment: Is there a solution to this? I am having this issue a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a portal to move autocomplete view to root component. To use portals on react native you need install `react-native-portal` package. I have modified your code on [snack](https://snack.expo.io/Bye3gFTk8) to include `react-native-portal`

Comment: Do you have any idea why in reactJS portals are built-in, but not in React Native? Also what about [react-native-portalize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-portalize)? seems more recent

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to using the custom dropdowns like

`https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown`
`https://github.com/maxkordiyak/react-native-dropdown-autocomplete#readme`

Please check these libraries if you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved your issue of pressed or scrolled searching data inside `Scrollview`, by adding `isHideScroll` state into `onPress` listener. `isHideScroll` Flag is used to show and hide Scrollview conditionally. Please check following expo snack code:-

https://snack.expo.io/@vishal7008/scroll-and-press-issue

**But it is not the best approach to doing search data from list**

You need to add `FlatList` in place of `ScrollView` and search data using `filter` function. Please check the below added example code and expo snack link.

https://snack.expo.io/@vishal7008/searching-list

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isHideList: true,
      searchText: '',
      listData: [
        {name: 'Bread'},
        {name: 'Cookies'},
        {name: 'Biscuit'},
        {name: 'Chocolate'},
      ],
      localData: [
        {name: 'Bread'},
        {name: 'Cookies'},
        {name: 'Biscuit'},
        {name: 'Chocolate'},
      ],
    };
  }

  selectOnClick = () => {
    this.setState({isHideList:false})
  };
  _renderListView = ({item, index}) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.listItemView}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.selectOnClick()}>
          <Text allowFontScaling={false} style={styles.listText}>
            {item.name}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };
  _searchFoodItem = value => {
    const newData = this.state.localData.filter(function(item) {
      let itemData = item.name.toUpperCase();
      let textData = value.toUpperCase();
      return itemData.startsWith(textData);
    });
    if (value == '') {
      this.setState({
        isHideList: false,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isHideList: true,
      });
    }
    this.setState({
      listData: [...newData],
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.selectedTagsContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.searchInput}
            placeholderTextColor="#9B6B6B"
            placeholder="Select 3 tags"
            onChangeText={text => {
              this._searchFoodItem(text);
            }}
          />
        </View>
        {this.state.isHideList && (
          <View style={styles.listStyle}>
            <FlatList
              nestedScrollEnabled={true}
              data={this.state.listData}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
              renderItem={(item, index) =>
                this._renderListView(item, index)
              }
              bounces={false}
              keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
              alwaysBounceVertical={false}
            />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  listStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    borderRadius: 2,
    position: 'absolute',
    width: '60%',
    zIndex: 1,
    marginLeft: 25,
    marginTop: 104,
    maxHeight:150,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  selectedTagsContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20,
    marginTop: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#F3F3F3',
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  listText: {
    padding: 10,
    width: '100%',
    color: 'black',
    marginTop: 7,
  },
  listItemView: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 10,
  },
  searchInput: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 50,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    color: '#6B6B6B',
    fontSize: 10,
  },
});
```